# Groovy and Junit

Tags: gradle, groovy, junit

I'm running the following JUnit tests in my Gradle plugin:

```
import org.junit.*
import org.gradle.testfixtures.ProjectBuilder
import org.gradle.api.Project

public class UmpleIntegrationTests {
    private static Project testProject

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        testProject = ProjectBuilder.builder().build()
        testProject.plugins.apply 'umple.gradle.plugin'
    }

    @Test
    public void umpleApplyPluginToProject() {      
        assertTrue(testProject.getPlugins().hasPlugin('umple.gradle.plugin'))
    }

    @Test
    public void umplePluginAddsTaskToProject() {
        assertTrue(testProject.tasks.getByName('generateSource') != null)
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error it's essentially the same for both the other test):

```
UmpleIntegrationTests > umplePluginAddsTaskToProject FAILED
    groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: UmpleIntegrationTests.assertTrue() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Boolean) values: [true]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:81)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
        at UmpleIntegrationTests.umplePluginAddsTaskToProject(UmplePluginIntegrationTests.groovy:21)
```

Why doesn't the assert method realize that `true` is a boolean? Also, this code works if I declare and initialize a new `testProject` in each test method. Not sure why it works that way but not this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is not the parameter type. 
You have to add a static import like 

`import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue`

to have access to the static `assertTrue` method. Alternatively you can call `Assert.assertTrue(...)`